# Select list element where a field has the min value

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a named list as follows:

```
myListOfPeople = [{'ID': 0, 'Name': 'Mary', 'Age': 25}, {'ID': 1, 'Name': 'John', 'Age': 28}]
```

I want to select the element (not only the field) where an specific field meets certain criteria, e.g., the element with the minimum 'Age'. Something like:

```
youngerPerson = [person for person in myListOfPeople if person = ***person with minimum age***]
```

And will get as answer:

```
>>youngerPerson: {'ID': 0, 'Name': Mary, 'Age': 25}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `key` parameter of `min`:

```
>>> myListOfPeople = [{'ID': 0, 'Name': 'Mary', 'Age': 25}, {'ID': 1, 'Name': 'John', 'Age': 28}]
>>> 
>>> min(myListOfPeople, key=lambda x: x["Age"])
{'ID': 0, 'Name': 'Mary', 'Age': 25}
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) :

```
from operator import itemgetter
myListOfPeople = [{'ID': 0, 'Name': 'Mary', 'Age': 25}, {'ID': 1, 'Name': 'John', 'Age': 28}]
sorted(myListOfPeople, key=itemgetter('Age'))[0]
# {'ID': 0, 'Name': 'Mary', 'Age': 25}
```